# C++ equality testing 'Object'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C# it's possible to test equality for any object against any object since everything inherits from Object.

In C++ this is not the case. I would like to overload the == operator passing in any unknown class and check at runtime for inequality, rather than compile time. (I get the error `binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type`).

Right now I want this for TDD purposes.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by equality? There are some ways to define what equality means, which IMHO is one of the reasons you can't compare arbitrary objects in `C++`. Some options: Same object (i.e. address), bitwise equal, conceptually equal, ...

Comment: TDD in strongly typed languages generally requires you to decide what types you're dealing with as you write the test.

Comment: @MarkusMayr in this case conceptually equal

Comment: I want to stress that this is one of the worst design decisions you could probably make. Reference identity is barely useful, but you would mix it with another definition of equality. There is no easy way to tell which definition is in place. Just think about the mess: You add a meaningful implementation of `==` to one of your classes and tests start to fail. Definitely a no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C# it's possible to test equality for any object against any object since everything inherits from Object.

That’s just plain incorrect. While it’s true that every class inherits an `Equals` method, this method doesn’t necessarily do anything meaningful unless it’s been overridden.

You can achieve the same in C++ but it’s quite bad practice and probably not what you want:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
bool equals(A const& a, B const& b) {
    return reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&a) == reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&b);
}
```

… this would be your fallback case (implementing reference identity<sup>1</sup>). Now you can add one where the types implement an appropriate operator (via SFINAE):

```
template <typename T>
auto equals(T const& a, T const& b) -> decltype(a == b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

However, to reiterate, this is neither advised nor generally helpful. It’s mostly nonsensical – either you already know that (and how) you can compare your objects or the comparison doesn’t make sense to begin with.

C#’s design is decidedly bad. There simply is no general “equality” concept, and C#’s `Object` type is over-specified in this regard.

---

<sup>1</sup> For `struct`s, C# implements memberwise equality which is arguably more meaningful but likewise usually not what’s wanted, and very inefficient to boot (since it’s using reflection).

Comment: It might be unimportant, but why do you `reinterpret_cast` to a `char*`? That tries to cast away the `const` of the reference. It's also not clear to me why you don't compare `void const*`s instead (via static/"implicit" cast).

Comment: @DyP Good point about the `const`-ness. The reason for using `char*` is that `char*` is a (poorly named) synonym for `byte*`, i.e. something logically approaching a memory address. I have no idea what `void*` is (apart from an erased type). I don’t use it.

Comment: What are some reasons this is not recommended?

Comment: @happygilmore Like I said, because it makes no sense. A generic equality comparison isn’t a meaningful operation. Implementing it will only mask logic bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Imitating the C# mechanism gives (besides C# has no const):

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
    public:
    virtual ~Object() {}
    virtual bool Equals(const Object& other) const {
        // C# ReferenceEquals
        return this == &other;
    }
};

bool operator == (const Object& a, const Object& b) {
    std::cout << " Object == Object  ";
    // C# ReferenceEquals
    return &a == &b;
}

class Derived : public Object
{
    public:
    virtual bool Equals(const Object& other) const {
        // C# does a test if the object is null - not needed in C++
        const Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&other);
        if(derived) return Equals(*derived);
        else return false;
    }

    bool Equals(const Derived& other) const {
        // Compare the members.
        return true;
    }
};

// C# Guideline: Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended
bool operator == (const Derived& a, const Derived& b) {
    std::cout << "Derived == Derived ";
    // C#: Test references conditions - not needed in C++:
    //     if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;
    //     if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null)) return false;
    return a.Equals(b);
}


// Test

template <typename A, typename B>
void compare(const char* what, const A& a, const B& b) {
    std::cout << what << ": ";
    std::cout << ((a == b) ? "True  " : "False ");
    std::cout << " Equals: " << ((a.Equals(b)) ? "True  " : "False ") << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Derived a;
    Derived b;
    Object& c = a;
    Object& d = b;
    compare("a == b", a, b);
    compare("a == c", a, c);
    compare("e == d", c, d);
}
```

Output:

```
a == b: Derived == Derived True   Equals: True  
a == c:  Object == Object  True   Equals: True  
e == d:  Object == Object  False  Equals: True
```

I do not recommend to this in C++.

Notes (From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Equals is a virtual method, enabling any class to override its
>   implementation. Any class that represents a value, essentially any
>   value type, or a set of values as a group, such as a complex number
>   class, should override Equals. If the type implements IComparable, it
>   should override Equals.
>
> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by
>   determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference
>   types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this
>   functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in
>   the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare
>   value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as
>   immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they
>   have the same value. Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is
>   not recommended.